# Is there a way to use scipy.optimize with only integer values?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, query-optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm using scipy.optimize.minimize to optimize a real-world problem for which the answers can only be integers. 
But I want it optimized with integer values (rounding all x to the nearest whole number doesn't always give the minimum). 
Is there a way to use scipy.optimize.minimize with only integer values?

Comment: Maybe [Z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) is helpful for this situation? If you provided some more detail, some demo data and some example code, people could shed more light on your question.

Comment: I don't think scipy.optimize has much to offer for discrete optimization.

Comment: Check minimize_scalar. Maybe your function is scalar or can be transformed to one

Comment: Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236863/)